# Copying multiple tables using SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, odbc, quickbooks, dataflowtask

I am trying to design an SSIS package which copy about 50+ tables from an ODBC DataSource (QuickBooks DB) to an SQL DB.
Should I create 50 Data Flow Task to do this ?
What is the best way to do this ? 
Putting DFT inside a Loop, and reading the tables ?  Or 50+ Data Flow Tasks ???

Answer (score 3):

You can create 50 Data Flow Tasks, but you don't have to.

It is possible to have multiple independent sources-destinations in the same DFT.
This will be not as flexible, because you can run single DFT separately from the package (while debugging), but you cannot run a piece of DFT without modifying it (as far as I know).

Depending on which option you choose, I see a couple of ways to save yourself from mundane work with 50+ tables:

a) Let [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186943.aspx) do the boring work for you.
The best about this tool is that it can create a .dtsx package.

So, with the wizard, you can:

- select for importing all 50+ tables from ODBC DataSource
- instead of running the wizard till the end, save the result as a .dtsx package.
- open the package in Visual Studio with SQL Server Data Tools
- modify the package up to your needs (for example logically regrouping the tables in different DFTs, adding any additional transformations).

b) Manually edit the package code (some [BIML](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/) knowledge might be needed):

- In Visual Studio with SQL Server Data Tools, create 1 DFT which will be your sample.
- In Solution Exporer, right-click on your package, select View Code.
- Either copy/paste the DFT 50+ times, changing the table names, or maybe you will even manage to automate your BIML somehow to avoid copy/paste